# Is it possible to send a transaction to be executed on a particular block?

Tags: transaction-propagation

Is it possible to send a transaction to the Ethereum network to be executed earliest from a certain block number?

So i.e.

Now it's block 111 and I want to have my transaction in block 115 (If it's accepted with that gas price).

Or that the transaction will be executed in block 115 and if the gas price is to low do block 116 with gas price times 2?

And do I need to run my own full node for this?

EDIT:

The suggested duplicate only anwsers part of the question.

Wouldn't it be so that if you know the pending transactions you can sum the gas limits and then know that the top X transactions will be included in the next block. If you then set you gas limit to be higher then one of those that it will be included?

Although [here](https://etherscan.io/txsPending?sort=gasprice&order=desc) I can see pending transaction, this includes the ones in the current block. Is it possible to only see the ones which haven't been included yet and do I need to run a full/mining node for this

Comment: In response to your edit: that still doesn't _guarantee_ your transaction will be included. Miners can effectively choose whatever transactions they like when creating a block (or no transactions at all). They might not even be following a rule of "higher gas price first" - it's entirely up to them.

Comment: @RichardHorrocks , I understand, it's not 100% certain, but don't almost all miners just use highest gas price first, so in general this would work? And do you know how to see only not-included pending transactions?

Comment: Under normal operation, you would _expect_ them to pick transactions by highest price first, yes. But there might be times when it would be more profitable for a miner (or pool) to do something else. (e.g. Empty blocks to ensure fast propagation; blocks containing their own transactions [front-running]; blocks containing transactions from users in their pool [pool front-running]; high gas _limit_ transactions being given lower priority; etc.). If you don't care so much about guaranteeing inclusion in a specific block, then perhaps these don't matter so much.

Comment: For the pending transactions: doesn't the list on EtherScan only show the transactions not included in a block yet? Or does their list not get updated when a transaction is moved from pending to included state?

Comment: @RichardHorrocks if I see transactions in the pending list. Which if I click on them show, "TxReceipt Status:Success" I believe this means they are included no?